# how to return to executing loop after handling KeyboardInterrupt in python

Tags: python, loops, keyboardinterrupt

I have a code that looks like this:

```
some_list = []
try:
    while True:
        ... code that uses the list ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ... code that modifies the list ...
```

after handling this exception, how do I return to executing this loop without nesting the loop?

Comment: You can not return to the loop after catching the exception. Instead use the `try-catch` block within the loop so you can continue iterating after an exception has been caught.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply re-structure your code to swap the loop with the `try/catch`

See this as example:

```
from time import sleep

some_list = []

while True:
    try:
        print(some_list)
        sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        some_list.append("1")
```